# Problems using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in custom c# Powershell CmdLet

Tags: c#, powershell

I run into a version conflict when trying to write my own CmdLet in C# (.NET Framework 4.7.2) using `Microsoft.Data.SqlCLient` - just these few lines of code are always resulting in some errors because `SqlClient` wants to load `System.Memory` version 4.0.1.1 - I need this dll for other nuget packages and have updated to latest version - I found no solution how to prevent `SqlClient` to use the old version of `System.Memory`

```
public class CmdLetEnvironment
{
    public static bool Connected = false;

    [System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet(System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommunications.Connect, "RDTest")]
    public class RDEnvironmentConnectCommand : System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet
    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestLocalOMA1;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False");
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex.InnerException;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I always get:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any help on this issue? I have tried so many different things (like `app.config` settings) but nothing seems to work

Comment: Usually this type of error is with the version of the library.  I usually in solution explorer delete the library under References.  Then add the library again from the menu Project : 
References.  You need Net 4.7.2 loaded.  From start button type Add or Remove Programs and check under Microsoft .Net Framework 4.7.2 if it is installed.

Comment: It is .NET 4.7.2 app - and it my real project I have a lot of nuget packages - can't reference an old version of any dll in a specific project - and if I change one reference there will be new errors - there must be a solution how to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in Powershell CmdLet - in app.config the binding is set to use version 4.0.1.2 - but it is not working - only in Powershell cmdlet - normal programs (Winform, Console, ...) it is working...

Comment: You don't specify version of a library.   Normally I would just put ontop of ps script : using assembly System.Data.SqlClient  I've found that SqlClinet is not usually installed on a machine unless SQL Server is installed on machine.

Comment: Publish your project to a file, with release configuration - should build with all required assemblies. Make sure the assembly files (.dlls) in the publish folder are then transferred to the same directory as you're importing your module dll from. Might not work but worth a shot?

Comment: If you've already tried that, I'd check out this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/resolving-dependency-conflicts?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for it - as Powershell is loading modules in different way then normal .NET application you need to override the assembly loading.

Add a constructor to the class and override AssemblyResolve to fix it - then you only need to ensure that all dll's are located in same directory then your CmdLet dll

```
[System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet(System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommunications.Connect, "RDTest")]
public class RDEnvironmentConnectCommand : System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet
{
        public RDEnvironmentConnectCommand()
        {
            var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            domain.AssemblyResolve += LoadAssembly;
        }

        private Assembly LoadAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            Assembly result = null;

                //Get current dll fullpath
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

                //Get folder of the executing .exe
                var folderPath = info.Directory.FullName;

                //Build potential fullpath to the loading assembly
                var assemblyName = args.Name.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                var assemblyExtension = "dll";
                var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, string.Format("{0}.{1}", assemblyName, assemblyExtension));


                if (File.Exists(assemblyPath))
                {
                    //Load the required assembly using our custom path
                    result = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Keep default loading
                    return args.RequestingAssembly;
                }

            return result;
        }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestLocalOMA1;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False");
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that could help other people running into the same issue :-)